# Energy of background radiation while falling into a black hole

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, time-dilation, gravitational-redshift, multiverse

As you fall into a black hole, the old story is you would be spaghettified - and this question is not about that.

However passing of time would be warped, so you would see the future of the universe unfold as you cross the event horizon? This means that you will be receiving the combined radiation energy of the universe's future in what I imagine is an instant.

To me, this implies that black holes have inside them the combined radiation energy of the entire universe, while simultaneously for us outside of the black hole - they don't.

Purely in terms of energy, every black hole contains within them an entire universe of energy - **as seen from *inside* the black hole**?

To summarize my questions:

1. Beyond the event horizon, does the blue shift caused by time dilation overcome the red shift caused by acceleration toward the black hole?
2. Would all black holes receive the combined radiation of rest of the universe and would the universe have to be open, flat or closed for this to hold true?
3. How does black hole evaporation fit into this?

I've been obsessed with this idea, that becomes a consequence of this. It basically means that *if* any particle in the universe eventually will end up inside a black hole - it already has entered that black hole *as seen from within that black hole*.

So in a collapsing universe, a black hole can be as "rich" as our entire universe in terms of mass and energy. Every black hole in the universe contains the entire universe. The mass inside it would simply be the future of the mass we have here.

This leads to a final question: Where can I read other peoples thoughts on this subject?

Comment: Surely black holes only contain the energy that actually falls onto them, which will only be all the energy of the universe if the universe is shaped such that all paths eventually lead to black holes (and therefore all those holes will merge). But if the universe has no boundaries then not all energy will fall into the hole(s).

Comment: @patstew You have to consider time dilation. A BH will continue to exists for trillions of years (our time), and over that time it will accumulate a lot of energy (if not all) as both matter and radiation. Inside the BH, these trillions of years will pass in what could amount to seconds. Due to relativity, one BH will see the other evaporate, while the other sees the first evaporate.

Comment: But unless the universe collapses, most worldlines won't intersect the hole no matter how long you wait.

Comment: @patstew In this scenario, it seems plausible that the universe is collapsing into many black holes continuously and *relatively* simultaneously. Sometimes black holes merge, other times they evaporate and their radiation will eventually contribute to other black holes. We are talking on time scales that are incredibly time shifted - 10^100 "earth years" may be a blink of an eye for an ultra massive black hole.